# How to get address of untyped const data?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

In a common Delphi pattern, i am passing a value as an **untyped const** to a function:

```
procedure DoSomething(const Something; SomethingLength: Integer);
begin
   //...
end;
```

In this example, i happen to be passing Windows [`FORMATETC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure:

```
procedure Test;
var
   omgp: TFormatEtc;
begin
   omgp := Default(TFormatEtc);
   omgp.cfFormat := RegisterClipboardFormat('CF_PNG');
   omgp.ptd := nil;
   omgp.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT or DVASPECT_THUMBNAIL;
   omgp.lindex := -1; //all pages
   omgp.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;

   DoSomething(omgp, SizeOf(omgp));
end;
```

I need to get the *address* of this data, so i can pass it to <strike>an underlying Windows function</strike> something that requires the pointer to the data.

In order to do this, i have always used `Pointer(@data)`:

```
procedure DoSomething(const Something; SomethingLength: Integer);
begin
   SomethingThatNeedsAPointer(Pointer(@Something));
end;
```

<strike>Until this one API call, in one particular case, is failing (it's returning the wrong values).</strike> For no particular reason, I happened to look closely at the pointer value being passed. When i was checking <strike>every</strike>the parameter value in the debugger i noticed something horrifying. I noticed that:

```
@Something
Pointer(@Something)
```

return different values.

[image: Imgur]

- **`@Something`** should already be a pointer
- **`Pointer(@Something)`** should be a redundant cast

Which way is the *right* way to get the address of untyped data?

**Edit**: People went to lunch on something unrelated to the question. I've edited the question so that hopefully people will focus on the question, and not the example.

Comment: In XE2, @Salt and Pointer(@Salt) have the same value. If you are having problems you could cheat and use `absolute` to get the address. Declare a local variable of byte or something like that and absolute it to `salt`. Then get the address of your local variable.

Comment: Long string variables (ansi or unicode) point to start of character data. Pass 'Pointer(salt)' to DoSomething, or just 'salt' and compiler will handle it.

Comment: Your code does not compile. DoSomething takes 2 arguments.

Comment: As for @Salt/Pointer(@Salt) don't trust the debugger. Check that with trace logging.

Comment: Finally, using a string to hold binary data is playing with fire. Expect locale related failures for non ASCII data. It's binary. Don't pretend otherwise. You aren't coding in PHP, you have a choice.

Comment: Storing binary in a string is like pouring molten steel into a wooden box.

Comment: *People went to lunch on something unrelated to the question. I've edited the question so that hopefully people will focus on the question, and not the example.* Hardly. FWIW, I answered the question, and commented on text/binary matter. Your edit makes our answers seem rather odd now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was referring to the excursion into passing strings as untyped const.

Comment: Ok. As in @Sertac's comment. It's a valid comment. FWIW, I don't like passing `salt[1]`. What if salt is empty? `Pointer(salt)^` is better. Modulo the concerns with treating text as binary. Anyway, you are never going to avoid people commenting on side issues. It's how programmers think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Salt` wasn't empty; i know because i wrote the example code to have it not empty. If `salt` was empty, then i would not have been able to use it in this hypothetical example. And it it's not just a harmless side-diversion into best practices of how to pass a string of AnsiChars. People actually confused the issue enough, thought it was exposing it as the best practice, that the question was downvoted into negative. I **had** to separate the question from the example; lest people continue think the example had something to do with the question.

Comment: @Ian your question was already down voted once when I posted that comment. I don't think, also, that it's got any effect on the other, although it's impossible to say for sure unless the voter commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a debugger bug, whereby the debugger is mis-reporting the value of `Pointer(@Salt)`. I can reproduce the fault in XE5, XE6 and XE7, but not in XE4 and XE8. So it seems that this is a defect introduced in XE5 and removed in XE8.

Whenever you see an issue like this, a debugger fault is always a possibility. In this case we can demonstrate that the fault lies in the debugger with this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure DoSomething(const Salt; SaltLength: Integer);
begin
  Writeln(IntToHex(NativeUInt(Pointer(@Salt)), 8));
  Writeln(IntToHex(NativeUInt(@Salt), 8));
end;

procedure Test;
var
  salt: AnsiString;
begin
  salt := 'salt';
  DoSomething(salt[1], Length(salt));
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

This program outputs:

```
007C9BD4
007C9BD4
```

even though `@Salt` and `Pointer(@Salt)` are accorded different values by the debugger.

Note that this program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure DoSomething(const Salt; SaltLength: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  P: PAnsiChar;
begin
  P := @Salt;
  for i := 0 to SaltLength-1 do
  begin
    Writeln(P^);
    inc(P);
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  salt: AnsiString;
begin
  salt := 'salt';
  DoSomething(salt[1], Length(salt));
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

outputs:

```
s
a
l
t
```

Comment: Ugh. **Another** bug in Delphi? We've had the new version of Delphi for nearly a year and we're *still* trying to release an application with it. Why, oh why, didn't i just upgrade to Delphi 7.

Comment: D5 was hardly bug free, but you had at least got used to those bugs!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your case in XE8.
The debugger shows same address for both  `@Salt` and `Pointer(@Salt)`.

Likewise the output of this test snippet is identical.
I can only assume that what the debugger is telling you is untrue somehow.

(**Update**: A test in XE7 reproduces the error in the debugger. The outcome of the snippet is the same though.)

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure Test1(p: Pointer);
begin
  WriteLn(Cardinal(p));
end;

procedure Test(const Salt);
begin
  Test1(@Salt);
  Test1(Pointer(@Salt));
  Test1(Addr(Salt));
end;

var
  s:AnsiString;
begin
  s := 'Test';
  Test( s[1]);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: The debugger defect appears to have been fixed in XE8, but is present in earlier versions

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I can also reproduce in XE7. Addr(Salt) in the watch list is ok as well.